# How to parse this DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetimeoffset

I'm getting a DateTimeOffset string as **"2018-10-16T193850+0200"**, but I think it's none of the standard formats. Mainly, the "+0200" part is not standard, because it lacks the colon.

What format do I have to specify to parse DateTimeOffsets like this?

Comment: I think it's non-standard because the date is expanded (has hyphens) but the time and time offset are basic (lack colons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
DateTimeOffset offsetDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    "2018-10-16T193850+0200",
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmsszzzz",
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Read: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Would DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2018-10-16T193850+0200", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmsszzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) not suffice?

Comment: @Bas: Yes because it's the same. If you call that overload `ParseExact` will call the one i use above and pass `DateTimeStyles.None` as fourth argument.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately setting [DateTimeInfo.TimeSeparator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator?view=netframework-4.7.2) to empty string won't help.

But you can use [DateTimeOffset.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) as follows:

```
DateTimeOffset date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2018-10-16T193850+0200", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH''mm''ss''K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

The trick is to specify 'K' format specifier in order to accept all kinds of offsets. Additionally to the above date string the following will be parsed correctly as well:

"2018-10-16T193850Z" - UTC

"2018-10-16T193850" - local time

EDIT
My answer is similar to Tim Schmelter's one, except by the 'K' part.